# Как задать текстовое значение глобальной переменной в lambda функции?

Tags: python, lambda, connect, globals

Работаю с кнопками.
Такой коннект функционирует:

`button.clicked.connect(lambda : button.setIcon(QIcon('my_button.png')))`

При клике на кнопке устанавливается изображение.

А вот такой - нет (появляются ошибки):

`button.clicked.connect(lambda : my_global.var = 'OK')`

Как в лямбде прописать присвоение текстового значения глобальной переменной?
**var** объявляется в модуле **my_global** и является глобальной переменной. Хочу через лямбду присвоить ей другое значение при нажатии кнопки, без написания отдельных функций. Если такое вообще возможно.

Comment: Создать процедуру и её вызывать в lambda, а в ней менять my_global.var = 'OK'

Comment: В самой лямбде - никак. Вообще, межмодульные глобальные переменные - плохая идея.